# How can the detail coefficients in discrete wavelet transform (DWT) be downsampled?

Tags: wavelet, highpass-filter, dwt

This question is asked with reference to this paragraph

> For the high-pass filter, the frequency content lies in the range $\frac{F_s}{4} \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{2}$. There is no content in the range $0 \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$. We can downsample by a factor of 2 in this case as well. The downsampling causes the frequency content in the $\frac{F_s}{4} \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{2}$ to be aliased into the range $0 \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$, but because there is no frequency content in this range, due to the high-pass filter, we have not lost any information.

from [Why is the high-pass filter result in a discrete wavelet transform (DWT) downsampled?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59013/why-is-the-high-pass-filter-result-in-a-discrete-wavelet-transform-dwt-downsam/59017#59017?newreg=18d16121368a41e09188d966a95bf9d4).

It is understandable that the approximation coefficients from DWT can be downsampled because the low passed filtered output retains the original sampling frequency ($F_s$) but has its frequency range is cut in half ($0 \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$).

However, how is it possible to shift the detail coefficients from its output range of ($\frac{F_s}{4} \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{2}$) to ($0 \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$) as specified in the link above? A downsample should change the range of detail coefficients to ($\frac{F_s}{8} \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$), meaning majority of the information from the detail coefficients is lost. The fact that there is no content in the range of ($0 \rightarrow \frac{F_s}{4}$) should not matter in this argument.

Comment: The text you cite explains this quite well. What do you have problems with? Are you familiar the aliasing and "bandpass sampling"? See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling#:~:text=In%20signal%20processing%2C%20undersampling%20or,able%20to%20reconstruct%20the%20signal.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not familiar with bandpass sampling. I know the concept of fundamental frequency and its harmonics but I was not aware of its applications in bandpass sampling. Thank you for pointing me towards the correct direction. 

As a follow-up question, to reconstruct the under-sampled signal, we need an additional information of the original frequency range is required. Only then we can use inverse Fourier transform get back the original signal at its original frequency. Am I right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with fundamentals and harmonics. You can reconstruct the original high pass signal without any additional information. Roughly speaking you shift the aliased spectrum to the upper half and fill the lower half with zeros. Then you can do an inverse FFT. Off course there are always some practical details to work out, like finite filters, etc.

Comment: From harmonics I know that frequencies of different integer multiples can be resonating within the same length. In a similar fashion, we can shift the high pass signal to a lower frequency band only because we know that the both high and low frequency signals are integer multiples from each other. Right? To clear up my question on additional info required to reconstruct an under-sampled signal, I know that in DWT, the integer multiple is always 2, hence no additional info is needed. However, for other undersampled signals without this knowledge, we have to know the original freq range correct?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with harmonics but is a general property of the sampling theorem. A signal that's both discrete in time in frequency is also periodic in time and frequency. The frequency period is the sample rate. As long as you have one complete period it doesn't matter which one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the low-pass and the high-pass filters are not perfect in practice, there will be aliasing in general after the downsampling operation. However, this is not always noticeable: this depends on the richness of the signal in each frequency band. The low-pass filtering helps as well.

I display thereafter an example from image processing where the aliasing in the center of the bottom right image is visible as a Moiré pattern on the tiles of the roof.

[image: Moiré aliasing patterns in discrete wavelet transform]

But what is important is that the low-pass filter and the high-pass one are build together so that the aliasing on both sides cancels itself when doing the inverse wavelet transform.

However, if you perform some processing on the wavelet coefficients before reconstruction, then you may touch coefficients that contribute to aliasing cancellation, and you may end up with some aliasing in the reconstructed image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does it mean that undersampling the higher frequency components (detail coefficients of the DWT) does bring about some aliasing effect during reconstruction? Since the high pass filters are imperfect and there will always be low magnitude signals remaining in the low frequency ranges.

Comment: No. In reconstruction, upsampled and re-filtered A and D coefficients, that separately were aliased, will be blending in a way that cancels previous aliases